# HTML line break without <br/> or \n?

Tags: javascript, html

I have made a function that types string letter by letter into .html

```
var i = 0;
text = "lorem ipsum" + "</br>" + "lorem ipsum";
function type_it() {
if (i < text.length) {
    info_text.innerHTML += text.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(type_it, 50);
    }
}
```

current output is "lorem ipsum <\br> lorem ipsum"
 while i need
 "lorem ipsum .
lorem ipsum".
the problem is I'm unable to use `<\br>` or `\n` to break text lines. The function types it as a string and they are not inserted into DOM

Comment: what are you having specifically problems with.?

Comment: `I'm unable to use <br> or \n to break text lines` <- Why are you unable to use those tags?

Comment: function types it as a string and they are not inserted into DOM

Comment: "unable to" as in "doesn't work" or "unable to" as in "not allowed to"?

Comment: @Wiktor Kisielewski you don't want to use `<br> or \n` or they are not woking?

Comment: it is inserted into html as a string so it does not work

Comment: What doesn't work? What output do you want?

Comment: @Wiktor Kisielewski update the code to show how are you doing this/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `white-space: pre` to allow newlines (`\n`) to have an effect in HTML:

```js
var i = 0;
var info_text = document.getElementById('foo')
text = "lorem ipsum\nlorem ipsum";
function type_it() {
if (i < text.length) {
    info_text.innerHTML += text.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(type_it, 50);
    }
}

type_it()
```

```css
#foo {white-space: pre;}
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
```

... but that will only allow you to insert newlines, not any other HTML formatting.

Alternatively, you could modify your script to insert entire tags at once (`<br>`) instead of one character at a time.

This is necessary because to prevent the browser displaying partial tags as text: "`<b`" for example will display the `<` until the close bracket is written in.

Also, when adding html incrementally it seems the browser only interprets the tag it's just completed writing; it doesn't go back and reinterpret content that was already inserted -- so if, for example, your string includes `<b>bold</b>`, and you add to the innerHTML one letter or tag at a time, the tags won't be visible, but neither will the **bold**.

This is easily fixed by replacing the entire contents of the element at each iteration, instead of adding a single character each time; that way the browser interprets the full string as html at every step.

```js
var i = 0;
var info_text = document.getElementById('foo')
text = "lorem ipsum<br>lorem ipsum<p>more <b>tags, just <i>to</i></b> test</p><ul><li>one</li><li>two</li><li>three</li></ul>";

function type_it() {
  if (i < text.length) {
if (text.charAt(i) === '<') {
  // we've found a tag; find out how many characters it consists of 
  i = i + text.substr(i).indexOf('>') + 1
} else {
  // it's text, add a single character
  i++;
}
info_text.innerHTML = text.substring(0, i); 
setTimeout(type_it, 50);
  }
}

type_it()
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
```

(Incidentally, I want to point out that `</br>` is not correct HTML; you may be misremembering the XML-style self-closing tag `<br/>` but that is also not correct for HTML5.  Both errors are harmless, but ideally you would use the correct `<br>`.)

Answer (score 2):

use the tag `<p>` to write every paragraph.
so you will not have to use the `<br />` tags.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```js
var i = 0;
var text = "test";
var info_text = document.getElementById("info_text");

function type_it() {

if (i < text.length) {
    info_text.innerHTML += "<div>" + text.charAt(i) + "</div>";
    i++;
    setTimeout(type_it, 50);
    }
}

type_it();
```

```html
<div id="info_text"></div>
```

Comment: The question says without using <br> or \n.

Comment: I updated the code to wrap in a div. OP mentions "unable to" which could be won't work or system doesn't allow it.